# How to get the SyntaxToken.Kind in current version of Roslyn?

Tags: c#, roslyn

I'm trying to update a project which makes heavy use of comparison against SyntaxToken.Kind. This property appears to have disappeared in newer versions of Roslyn and I wondered if there an alternative method or an extension method I could write to get the same functionality?

The code has many references such as:

```
if (expression.OperatorToken.Kind == SyntaxKind.PlusEqualsToken)
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add a using for `Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Syntax`, and then use the `CSharpKind()` extension method.

Comment: Thanks Kevin, I was hoping to find an extension whereby I wouldn't have to change existing code, but that's cool.

Comment: We now share SyntaxNode between C# and VB, so Kind wouldn't make sense, unless the enum had all the kinds for both languages, which we didn't want.